# How do I detect if the user's font (DPI) is set to small, large, or something else?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, dpi

I need to find out if the user's screen is set to normal 96 dpi (small size), large 120 dpi fonts, or something else. How do I do that in VB.NET (preferred) or C#?

Comment: A native way (written in Delphi but only using the native Windows API): `var
  dc: HDC;
  res: integer;
begin
  dc := GetDC(0);
  if dc <> 0 then
    try
      res := GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSX);
    finally
      ReleaseDC(0, dc)
    end;`

Comment: As Andreas suggests, you can also call the Windows API functions `GetDC` and `GetDeviceCaps` in order to get this information, but you'll have to use P/Invoke to get at them from a .NET application, and there's little benefit in doing so since the `Graphics` class has already wrapped this up so nicely in managed code.

Comment: But anyway, **thanks for [paying your taxes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/14/182971.aspx)**!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *best* way is just to let the form resize itself automatically, based on the user's current DPI settings. To make it do that, just set the [`AutoScaleMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx) to `AutoScaleMode.Dpi` and enable the [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize.aspx) property. You can do this either from the Properties Window in the designer or though code:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi
    Me.AutoSize = True
End Sub
```

Or, if you need to know this information while *drawing* (such as in the [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event handler method), you can extract the information from the [`DpiX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.dpix.aspx) and [`DpiY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.dpiy.aspx) properties of the [`Graphics` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac148eb3.aspx) instance.

```
Private Sub myControl_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim dpiX As Single = e.Graphics.DpiX
    Dim dpiY As Single = e.Graphics.DpiY

    ' Do your drawing here
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Finally, if you need to determine the DPI level on-the-fly, you will have to create a temporary instance of the `Graphics` class for your form, and check the `DpiX` and `DpiY` properties, as shown above. The [`CreateGraphics` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) of the form class makes this very easy to do; just ensure that you wrap the creation of this object in a [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to avoid memory leaks. Sample code:

```
Dim dpiX As Single
Dim dpiY As Single

Using g As Graphics = myForm.CreateGraphics()
    dpiX = g.DpiX
    dpiY = g.DpiY
End Using
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks! But does the dpi relates to the screen size (X / Y) or the font size (X only available) ? In other words, can I be certain that dpiX = dpiY in all cases? Otherwise, the new font would look stretched, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Didier: Yes, normally dpiX will be equivalent to dpiY. If not, it would look stretched. It would depend on the resolution and the user's chosen DPI settings. The default small settings have dpiX = 96 and dpiY = 96. The default large settings have dpiX = 120 and dpiY = 120. You might check out [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464646.aspx) on high-DPI applications. The linked [how-to page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464660.aspx) is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [DpiX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.dpix.aspx) and [DpiY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.dpiy.aspx) properties. For example:

```
using (Graphics gfx = form.CreateGraphics())
{
    userDPI = (int)gfx.DpiX;
}
```

In VB:

```
Using gfx As Graphics = form.CreateGraphics()
    userDPI = CInt(gfx.DpiX)
End Using
```