# Determine what size font Windows 7 has set via C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detect if the user's font (DPI) is set to small, large, or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082733/how-do-i-detect-if-the-users-font-dpi-is-set-to-small-large-or-something-el)

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the setting as used in the picture below?

Thanks?

[image]

Comment: http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/c-programmatically-get-the-current-dpi-setting/

Comment: As an aside its worth noting that you can respond in case the user changes the setting while you're app is open. See the [MSDN article How to: Respond to Font Scheme Changes in a Windows Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229594.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Check under class SystemFonts. I don't think you need more than the default namespaces for this.

```
string name = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont.FontFamily.Name;
float size = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont.Size;
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemfonts.aspx  is the link to MSDN

Comment: The specific screen that the OP is asking about is DPI.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is already answered here:

[How to get Windows Display settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings)

The IconTitleFont information would just give you the font size whereas you seem to be looking for the magnification level.

Comment: I tried that but had the same results as some of the other users. The results weren't reliable.