# Published project not working on all computers?

Tags: vb.net

I have a working vb.net project which runs successfully on my host computer through the console. I've published it, installed it on other computers, and run it successfully on those machines. I have installed xampp which is necessary for the php to run behind the scenes as well, and again, everything runs perfectly.

However, this morning, I went to install it on another computer and something weird occurred. One of the labels on the window, overlapped into a text field. This sounds somewhat harmless, but the result was that the user could not use the text field, and so the app will not work.

Basically my question then is, is there some way to limit the formatting so that it will work on all computers? (I find this odd to ask, since the questionable computer is a windows 64 bit operating system as is the computer's I've installed on and the computer I'm currently on)

Comment: DPI settings will most probably be different...

Comment: Understandable. I assumed the published version though would be capable of resizing appropriately, so that no overlaps would occur. Is there a way to manually do this?

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET? and what is VBA.NET (Do you mean VBA or VB.NET)?

Comment: its being designed in visual basic

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the DPI settings are causing your issue. You can verify this by changing the DPI settings back to 100%, restart the computer and see if it makes any difference. See [this Link](https://support.corel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001485408-Display-Options-How-to-change-DPI-Scaling-Level-for-displays-in-Windows-10-) on how you can change your DPI settings.

I can't give you a straight up answer on how you can solve this issue that you are experiencing. But I am going to give you a lead to how you can solve it.

See the links below for two other threads on the issue:

- [Creating a DPI-Aware Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application)
- [How do I detect if the user's font (DPI)...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082733/how-do-i-detect-if-the-users-font-dpi-is-set-to-small-large-or-something-el)

Some more information on the matter:

1. Creating an application that will scale correctly on other computers will depend if you have written the application in 100% DPI yourself. If you have not, then you might experience issues downscaling or upscaling the application size to fit other DPI settings.
2. You want the application to scale depending on user settings. You can use the following code to do so:

   ```
   Public Sub New()
       InitializeComponent()

       Me.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi
       Me.AutoSize = True
   End Sub
   ```

   Keep in mind, this will scale the current form, you will have to do the same for all other forms that you have in your application. See bullet-point link 2 for more information on this.
3. If you have used containers such as Panel, TableLayoutPanel, etc. whilst creating your form, you will have a better time making the form fit the other DPI settings. (I know this from personal experience with application scaling.)